# Apply CSS to searched history drop down

Tags: html, css

An input element is used for searching feature. I think it is a browser built-in feature to record searched inputs. So when users search again for something they have already searched before, this dropdown div opens up as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV1ck.png)

Can someone please suggest how to apply CSS to this dropdown div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's called auto-complete, and it's handled by the browser. There is no way to style the dropdown that's generated.

Comment: If you want a custom select or autocomplete, you need to build it yourself, this might help you out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Comment: @BenM - if that dropdown is generated as you said, how come google.com dropdown is generated differently to mine? (https://snipboard.io/QdrUpz.jpg)

Comment: @mindOverFlow Because they're using a custom autocomplete. There are many examples of these online, but the one that you see on Google isn't the default one generated by the browser.

Comment: _“It is that dropped down div that pops up when it shows searched records, i need to apply css to this div.”_ - show us your code containing that div then. If you can’t, because you have just a plain input field - then we _are_ talking about what is generally referred to as autocomplete (by the browser, not anything that makes AJAX requests in the background to find possible matches), and that does not use any “divs” that you could style; this is a UI component rendered by the browser outside of the realm you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-fill is an option that cannot be customized via CSS, but you could possibly make your own top results and customize that.

Source site: https://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/