# Use CSS to change appearance of drop down search results on a very old webpage?

Tags: css, search, history, dropdownbox

I found this topic: [Apply CSS to searched history drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871563/apply-css-to-searched-history-drop-down)

If I understood its comments correctly [not being a programmer but just a small time code tweaker]: it is pretty much impossible to change with CSS an already existing drop down list that shows previous search expressions of an input box?

I am trying to rework a site from 1990s and can only work with CSS on it, not touching the HTML files. The original code is this:

```
<form method="Post" action="/cgi-bin/-NAME-OF-THE-SITE-/the_search_form">

<hr>

<label for="search">Type text you would like to search for here: </label>
<input name="tquery" id="search" size="25" maxlength="60"> <p>

</p><center>
<input type="Submit" value="FIND"> <input type="Reset" value="CLEAR">
</center>

<hr>

</form>
```

I have managed to rework visually the `Submit` and `Reset` buttons and also the input box itself - but the drop down list showing itself below that box has [I recon] the default visuals of a given browser [as it looks are different in Firefox than in Opera]

I would also like to increase the `maxlengt` parameter [i.e. the number of signs allowed for input], but all I could do was the opposite - limiting it [below than original `60` value]

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, it is impossible to style autocomplete dropdowns.**

The autocomplete dropdowns are inserted in by the browser and can not be styled. However, people have found ways around it be creating there own custom dropdowns but this requires a lot of JS and a few more HTML elements. Here is a example here of a custom autocomplete search bar: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

So in your particular case just don't worry about it! If the browser styles the autocomplete differently then you had in mind it will be better for the users because it's consistent with what they are used to. One more option is to just turn off autocomplete entirely like this.

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

But again, you said you can only touch the styles!

Comment: That part about not worrying one one hand is reassuring - but on the other hand is not. Because nowadays websites have such individual visual styles applied to them that it is strange when you suddenly I see some robust element, that seems very out of place with the rest of a design. And any user who will use that CSS of mine [via Stylish plugin] will think that I simply forgot to take care o this element. But as you said, it is not possible to take care of it with CSS. Hard luck

Comment: But does this also mean that in the future CSS might be upgraded - and this what I am after will become possible?